# How do I split and combine python list elements when you need to omit elements at split points?

Tags: python, list, split

I am looking for a **compact and elegant** way without using itertools.

The function takes a string that comprises of parenthesis (an open bracket is guaranteed to have its matching close bracket) It then finds the sub-string within innermost brackets, reverses it in-place and removes the respective surrounding parentheses and returns the modified string.

```
def swap_innermost(self, s): # example s = "(u(love)i)" returns "(uevoli)"
    start= s.rfind('(')
    end= start + s[start:].find(')')
    found= (start != -1) and (end != -1) # find()/rfind() returns -1 when not found

    if found:
        part1= s[0:start] if start != 0 else ''                
        part2= s[start+1:end][::-1] # chew out ( char and reverse rest
        part3= s[end+1:] if end != len(s)-1 else '' # chew out ) char
            
        return part1+ part2+ part3
    else:
        return s
```

Comment: If you have a string like `((ab)cd(ef))` should it reverse both `ab` and `ef`? Similarly, if you have `((ab)cd(ef(gh)ij))` should it reverse both `ab` and `gh`?

Comment: The code should just take care of the last '(' and its associated ')'. A repeated outer loop when calls swap_innermost() multiple times until all the parenthesis are stripped and contents swapped will yield => ((ab)cd(ef)) will become ((ab)cdfe)... after second call (bacdfe).. after 3rd call  we get efdcab.